# how to hide null value in bar chart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, echarts

how to hide any null value from showing in bar chart??

in my case i want to hide these empty column in bar chart from showing.. only bar that have value will show

please refer picture below

[image]

the result supposely will hide all those null value and do not have big gap between bar. like example below.

[image]

as can see image hide `null` value bar and only show item that have value

example code as below

```js
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Forest', 'Steppe', 'Desert', 'Wetland']
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'right',
    top: 'center',
    feature: {
      mark: { show: true },
      dataView: { show: true, readOnly: false },
      magicType: { show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack'] },
      restore: { show: true },
      saveAsImage: { show: true }
    }
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      axisTick: { show: false },
      data: ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Forest',
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: 0,
      label: labelOption,
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390]
    },
    {
      name: 'Steppe',
      type: 'bar',
      label: labelOption,
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290]
    },
    {
      name: 'Desert',
      type: 'bar',
      label: labelOption,
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190]
    },
    {
      name: 'Wetland',
      type: 'bar',
      label: labelOption,
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [98, 77, 101, 99, 40]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Perhaps [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+echarts+hide+null)

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for suggestion.. i already search for it unfortunately it did not asnwer my question